# Getting "[object HTMLDivElement]" instead of its content?

Tags: javascript

I want to just create a copy of original `div`s inside of a new div with one case -
**Case 1 :**
copy those divs which are having `favourite` classes inside of a new div of id `fav_items`.

**I have already tried -**
I tried both `innerHTML` and `appendChild()` method .
When I tried `innerHTML` then it gave `[object HTMLDivElement]`
instead of real content . 
and When I tried `appendChild()` method then it moves the div from it's original position to a new div.

**Code :**
**HTML**

```
<div id="blog-posts">
      <div class="favourite">
        <p>Item 1.</p>
       <div>
       <div class="item">
        <p>Item 2.</p>
       <div>
       <div class="favourite">
        <p>Item 3.</p>
       <div>
</div>

<!-- Favourite Added items---------->
    <div id="cart_items">
        <h2>Your items :</h2>
    </div>
```

**Javascript uses innerHTML**

```
var cart_div = document.getElementById("cart_items");
      var fav_items = document.getElementsByClassName("favorite");
      for(let i = 0; i< fav_items.length; i++){
      cart_div.innerHTML += fav_items[i];
      }
```

**Javascript uses appendChild()**

```
var cart_div = document.getElementById("cart_items");
      var fav_items = document.getElementsByClassName("favourite");
      for(let i = 0; i< fav_items.length; i++){
      cart_div.appendChild(fav_items[i]);
      }
```

But when I use `appendChild()` method then it moves the div of class `favourite` from it's original position to a new div of id `cart_items`.
**Code preview using innerHTML**

```js
 var cart_div = document.getElementById("cart_items");
 var fav_items = document.getElementsByClassName("favourite");
          for(let i = 0; i< fav_items.length; i++){
          cart_div.innerHTML += fav_items[i];
          }
```

```html
<div id="blog-posts">
          <div class="favourite">
            <p>Item 1.</p>
           <div>
           <div class="item">
            <p>Item 2.</p>
           <div>
           <div class="favourite">
            <p>Item 3.</p>
           <div>
    </div>

    <!-- Favourite Added items---------->
        <div id="cart_items">
         <h2>Your items :</h2>
        </div>
```

**Code preview using appendChild()**

```js
var cart_div = document.getElementById("cart_items");
var fav_items = document.getElementsByClassName("favorite");
      for(let i = 0; i< fav_items.length; i++){
      cart_div.appendChild(fav_items[i]);
      }
```

```html
<div id="blog-posts">
          <div class="favourite">
            <p>Item 1.</p>
           <div>
           <div class="item">
            <p>Item 2.</p>
           <div>
           <div class="favourite">
            <p>Item 3.</p>
           <div>
    </div>

    <!-- Favourite Added items---------->
        <div id="cart_items">
         <h2>Your items :</h2>
        </div>
```

So how can I show the div of class `favourite` to the div of id `cart_items` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var cart_div = document.getElementById("cart_items");
var fav_items = document.getElementsByClassName("favourite");
for(let i = 0; i< fav_items.length; i++){
cart_div.innerHTML += fav_items[i].innerHTML;
}
```

I think by adding innerHTML to the fav_items you'll get what's inside.
Also you had a typo with classname 'favorite' instead of 'favourite'.

Comment: But It is not adding <div class="favourite"> , it only add its children . So I also want <div class="favourite"> (parent element)

Comment: Got it, but is it possible, without adding another div arround that ?

Comment: There probably is, but I don't know it from the top of my head and don't have the time right now to look for it.
Feel free to upvote/accept my answer if it helped/solved your problem! :)

Comment: try .outerHTML instead of .innerHTML

Answer (score 2):

Try .outerHTML instead of .innerHTML ,

```
var cart_div = document.getElementById("cart_items");
var fav_items = document.getElementsByClassName("favourite");
for(let i = 0; i< fav_items.length; i++){
  cart_div.innerHTML += fav_items[i].outerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting innerHTML expects you to write raw HTML, so it won't work with a list of DOM objects - which is what is indicated by `[object HTMLDivElement]`.

appendChild is a better option, but you need to duplicate the existing nodes (possibly with cloneNode() or another similar DOM method).