# Append an object instead of an element to a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have this `joinRoomInit` function :

```js
let joinRoomInit = async () => {
  // ...
  joinStream();
  client.on("user-published", handleUserPublished);
};
```

It executes `joinStream` then wait for the `user-published` event to execute `handleUserPublished`.

`joinStream` and `handleUserPublished` are doing almost the same task:

```js
let joinStream = async () => {

  // create  new video__container div dynamically
  var playerDiv = document.createElement("div"); // create div 1
  playerDiv.className = "video__container"; // add class
  playerDiv.id = `user-container-${uid}`; // add id
  var videoPlayerDiv = document.createElement("div"); // create div 2
  videoPlayerDiv.className = "video-player"; // add class
  videoPlayerDiv.id = `user-${uid}`; // add id
  playerDiv.appendChild(videoPlayerDiv); // append div 2 to div 1

  // append it to streams__container
  document
    .getElementById("streams__container")
    .insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", playerDiv);

  // play the video  on the div with user-${uid} ID
  localTracks[1].play(`user-${uid}`);
  // publishing (trigger user-publish event)
  await client.publish([localTracks[0], localTracks[1]]);
};
```

```js
let handleUserPublished2 = async (user) => {

  console.log("user: ", user);

  // create  new video__container div dynamically
  var playerDivRemote = document.createElement("div");
  playerDivRemote.className = "video__container";
  playerDivRemote.id = `user-container-${user.uid}`;
  var videoPlayerDivRemote = document.createElement("div");
  videoPlayerDivRemote.className = "video-player";
  videoPlayerDivRemote.id = `user-${user.uid}`;
  playerDivRemote.appendChild(videoPlayerDivRemote);

  console.log("playerDivRemote: ", playerDivRemote);

  document
    .getElementById("streams__container")
    .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", playerDivRemote);

  // play the video  on the div with user-${uid} ID
  user.videoTrack.play(`user-${user.uid}`);
};
```

`joinStream` works fine, it creates a div and appends it to `streams__container`, However, `handleUserPublished` appends a `"[object HtmlDivElement]"` to the DOM even when the div is properly created, I can see it in the [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91IP0.jpg).

I wonder what's the reason behind this, couldn't find out the difference.

Comment: I believe your question already be answered here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56461743/getting-object-htmldivelement-instead-of-its-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inserts an element node, you can try [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) instead of `insertAdjacentHTML` in the following:

```
....
....
document
  .getElementById("streams__container")
  .insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", playerDivRemote);
....
....
```